# How to rename linked comps between Premiere and After Effects

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I create a lot of linked comps from Premiere into After Effects.
What's the right approach to renaming them, so that they don't all end up with generic meaningless names?

By default they are named:
"Project Name Linked Comp 01", 02 etc.

[Adobe says I can rename them](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/user-guide.html/premiere-pro/using/dynamic-link.ug.html) in AE without breaking links... Renaming them in Premiere seems to break the link.

What's the best way to rename them in both apps without breaking links?